# Assign incremental id based on number series in ordered sql table

Tags: sql, dbt

My table of interview candidates has three columns and looks like this (**attempt** is what I want to calculate):

| candidate_id | interview_stage | stage_reached_at | attempt <- want to calculate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2019-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2019-01-03 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-11-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2019-11-02 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-01-02 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-01-03 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-01-04 | 3 |

The table represents candidate_id 1 who has had 3 separate interview attempts at a company.

- Made it to interview_stage 3 on the 1st attempt
- Made it to interview_stage 2 on the 2nd attempt
- Made it to interview_stage 4 on the 3d attempt

**Question:** Can I somehow use the number series if I order by stage_reached_at? As soon as the next step for a particular candidate_id is *lower* than the row before, I know it's a new process.

I want to be able to group on candidate_id and process_grouping at the end of the day.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Are the stage_reached_at dates correct? I'm a bit surprised that you want attempt 3 before attempt 2.

Comment: You are correct! My bad, I edited the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_interview_stage >= interview_stage then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by candidate_id order by stage_reached_at) as attempt
from (select t.*,
             lag(interview_stage) over (partition by candidate_id order by stage_reached_at) as prev_interview_stage
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note:  Your question specifically says "lower".  I wonder, though, if you really mean "lower or equal to".  If the latter, change the `>=` to `>`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked splendidly. However, the case function was flipped wrong. It worked the other way around:
`case when prev_interview_stage >= interview_stage then 1 else 0 end`